# Simply traversing through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is name_Scenario[i] iterating each individual char instead of each string in the array?

```
var num_Scenarios;
var num_Features;
var name_Scenario = ["Login", "Users", "Yo", "Whatsup", "Diablo 3", "Junglr", "Microsoft", "Another", "Hi", "Anyone", "O", "Happy", "Stuff", "Sleep", "Account"];
var desc_Scenario;

function normalGrid() {
    $("#tile-bank").remove();
    $("#content").append("<div id=\"tile-bank\"></div>");
    //Code where your data is received and you run addScenario() per interation
    //filler global vars that your data will replace
    num_Scenarios = 15;
    num_Features = 20;
    name_Scenario = "Login";
    desc_Scenario = "This is a description.";
    var add_to = $("#tile-bank");
    for (var i = 0; i < num_Scenarios; i++) {
        addScenario(add_to, num_Features, name_Scenario[i], desc_Scenario);
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery (hence the edit)

Comment: Did you try this at all? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n5Gx/), and it works just fine, must be something else you are doing that turns the array into a string.

Comment: This should work absolutely fine.

Comment: No need to downvote- added exact code

Comment: If you're getting just `h` then either you have other code that is somehow interfering, or what you pasted is not what you're using.

Comment: you need to do JSON.parse before iterating it.

Comment: You misled everyone with your question., make sure you know what you are asking and that it makes sense before you post

Comment: if it showing "h" on first index. It can be because it is received as a string in javascript. Are you getting array from ajax response?

Comment: @Ibu you could have just asked for additional details.

Comment: Wow. This question has radically changed since the first posting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `name_Scenario = "Login";` line , `name_Scenario` is a string or ,in other words,an array of `char`s,and your are iterating through that `char`s. Just remove that line.

```
for (var i = 0; i < name_Scenario.length; i++) {
//changed 'num' to 'name'--^       ^---added '.length' here
    addScenario(add_to, num_Features, name_Scenario[i], desc_Scenario);
}
```

Comment: Well how do I make it an array of strings?  And why does it default to chars?

Comment: Thank you, wow I couldn't find that after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your are redefining `name_Scenario`. It used to be an array, but by the time you get to calling an index on it with `[i]`, it's become a string.

Also, you don't need `num_Scenarios`. You can just use `nameScenario.length` (while it's still an array, of course!).

Answer (score 1):

You are overwiting the var var name_Scenario;

in the line 3 you do  = ["Login", "Users", "Yo", "Whatsup", "Diablo 3", "Junglr", "Microsoft", "Another", "Hi", "Anyone", "O", "Happy", "Stuff", "Sleep", "Account"];

then before the loop you do name_Scenario = "Login";